# Native elasticsearch facet script

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

is it possible to use native script in facets?

For example, when i run:

```
{
  "facets": {
    "judges": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "judges.untouched",
        "size": 10,
        "all_terms": false,
        "global_facets": true,
        "_script": {
          "script": "facet_matcher",
          "params": {
            "a": "b"
          },
          "lang": "native"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

it correctly use native facet provided in elasticsearch.yml

But when i fetch more facets, elasticsearch fail to parse the query:

```
{
  "facets": {
    "judges": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "judges.untouched",
        "size": 10,
        "all_terms": false,
        "global_facets": true,
        "_script": {
          "script": "facet_matcher",
          "params": {
            "a": "b"
          },
          "lang": "native"
        }
      }
    },
    "judges_selected": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "judges.untouched",
        "size": 10,
        "all_terms": false
      },
      "global_facets": false
    }
  }
}
```

with error:

```
... Parse Failure [No parser for element [judges_selected]]]; }]
```

What am i doing wrong? Is is possible to use facet script like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Elasticsearch is just getting confused by the `_script` element. Try this:

```
{
  "facets": {
    "judges": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "judges.untouched",
        "size": 10,
        "all_terms": false,
        "global_facets": true,
        "script": "facet_matcher",
        "params": {
          "a": "b"
        },
        "lang": "native"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to use 'term' variable in native script?

Comment: The value of the term will be provided to script using `setNextVar(name, value)` call. Override this method and when it's called with `"term"` in the `name` parameter save the `value` and use it in the following `run()` execution. Makes sense?